# Scrolling intoView for Dynamic input

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, input

please give me a hand. when the dynamic input is added it does not scroll into view. Right now as it sees, when the window is loaded it will scroll into view therefore I know it works but I can't get it to scroll into view for each last input as it is added. I'm guessing im screwing up somewhere with the window 'load', help!

```
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    
        console.log('product create JS working')

  

      var add_more_fields = document.getElementById("add_more_fields")
        var remove_fields = document.getElementById("remove_fields")
        var add_more_fields_ingredients = document.getElementById("add_more_fields_ingredients")
        var remove_fields_ingredients = document.getElementById("remove_fields_ingredients")
        var ingredient_list = document.getElementById('ingredient-list')
        var instruction_list = document.getElementById('instruction-list')
        var imageInput = document.querySelector('.imageInput')
        var imagePreview = document.querySelector('.product-preview')
        var buttonSubmit = document.querySelector('#button-for-submit')



   

     imageInput.onchange = evt => {
            const [file] = imageInput.files
            if (file) {
                imagePreview.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
                console.log(file.size + " this is the file size in bytes")
            }
        }



add_more_fields.onclick = function () {
    var node = document.createElement("li")
    var newField = document.createElement('input')
    newField.setAttribute('type', 'text')
    newField.setAttribute('name', 'directions[]')
    newField.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Add Instruction')
    node.appendChild(newField)
    instruction_list.appendChild(node)
    console.log('new field')
}
let items = document.querySelectorAll('#instruction-list li')
console.log(items)
let last = items[items.length - 1]
last.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center" })







remove_fields.onclick = function () {
    var input_tags = instruction_list.getElementsByTagName('li')
    if (input_tags.length > 1) {
        instruction_list.removeChild(input_tags[(input_tags.length) - 1])
    }
}



add_more_fields_ingredients.onclick = function () {
    var node = document.createElement("li")
    var newField = document.createElement('input')
    newField.setAttribute('type', 'text')
    newField.setAttribute('name', 'Ingredients[]')
    newField.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Add Ingredient')
    node.appendChild(newField)
    ingredient_list.appendChild(node)
}



   

     remove_fields_ingredients.onclick = function () {
            var input_tags = ingredient_list.getElementsByTagName('li')
            if (input_tags.length > 1) {
                ingredient_list.removeChild(input_tags[(input_tags.length) - 1])
            }
        }
    
    
    })
```

HTML / EJS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/product-creation.css' />
    <script defer src="../../javascripts/product-create.js"></script>
    <title>Upload a recipe</title>
</head>

<body>
    <%- include("partials/header.ejs") %>

        <div class="body-information">
            <section class="main-section">
                <div class="form-container" id="form-container">
                    <form class="productCreate-form" action="/recipes/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                        <div class="title-title">
                            <h3 class="recipe-pretitle">Recipe for</h3>
                            <div>
                                <label for="title">
                                    <% if (locals.errors && errors.title) { %>
                                        <div class="text-danger centerText errorBg">
                                            <%= errors.title.msg%>
                                        </div>
                                        <%} %>
                                            <input name="title" type="text" id="title" value="<%= locals.oldData && oldData.title ? oldData.title : ""%>" placeholder=" Name of dish">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class=" description-container">
                            <label class="description-label" for="description">A brief description of your dish: <br> (max 350 characters)</label>
                            <% if (locals.errors && errors.description) { %>
                                <div class="text-danger centerText errorBg">
                                    <%= errors.description.msg%>
                                </div>
                                <%} %>
                                    <textarea name="description" type="text" id="description" maxlength="350" cols="30" rows="5"><%= locals.oldData && oldData.description ? oldData.description : "" %></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="directions-ingredients-container">


                            <div class="ingredients-container">
                                <div class="label-ingredients"><label for="Ingredients">Ingredients:</label></div>
                                <div class="controls-ol-container">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <a href="#" id="add_more_fields_ingredients"><i class="fa fa-sm">Add Ingredient</i></a>
                                        <a href="#" id="remove_fields_ingredients"><i class="fa fa-sm">Remove last Ingredient</i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ingredient-list-container">
                                        <% if (locals.errors && errors.Ingredients) { %>
                                            <div class="text-danger centerText errorBg">
                                                <%= errors.Ingredients.msg%>
                                            </div>
                                            <%} %>
                                                <ol id="ingredient-list">
                                                    <% if (locals.oldData && oldData.Ingredients){ %>
                                                        <% oldData.Ingredients.forEach(function(element){ %>
                                                            <% if(element) {%>
                                                                <li><input type="text" name="Ingredients[]" value="<%=element ? element : "" %>"></li>
                                                                <% } else { %>
                                                                    <li><input type="text" name="Ingredients[]" placeholder="Add Ingredient" %>"></li>
                                                                    <% } %>
                                                                        <% }) %>

                                                                            <% } else if(!locals.oldData || !oldData.Ingredients){ %>
                                                                                <li><input type="text" name="Ingredients[]" placeholder="Add Ingredient"></li>
                                                                                <% } %>

                                                </ol>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div id="product-directions">
                                <div class="label-directions"><label for="directions">Cooking steps.</label></div>
                                <div class="controls-ol-container">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <a href="#" id="add_more_fields"><i class="fa fa-sm">Add step</i></a>
                                        <a href="#" id="remove_fields"><i class="fa fa-sm">Remove last step</i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="instruction-list-container">
                                        <% if (locals.errors && errors.directions) { %>
                                            <div class="text-danger centerText errorBg">
                                                <%= errors.directions.msg%>
                                            </div>
                                            <%} %>
                                                <ol id="instruction-list">
                                                    <% if (locals.oldData && oldData.directions){ %>
                                                        <% oldData.directions.forEach(function(element){ %>
                                                            <% if(element) { %>
                                                                <li><input type="text" name="directions[]" placeholder="Add Instruction" value="<%=element ? element :"" %> "></li>
                                                                <% } else { %>
                                                                    <li><input type="text" name="directions[]" placeholder="Add Instruction" %> "></li>
                                                                    <% } %>
                                                                        <% }) %>
                                                                            <% } else if(!locals.oldData || !oldData.directions){ %>
                                                                                <li><input type="text" name="directions[]" placeholder="Add Instruction"></li>
                                                                                <% } %>
                                                </ol>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="imageInputContainer">

                            <label id="image-label" for="image">
                                <p class="absolute-image-label">Choose an image</p>
                                <img class="product-preview">
                            </label>
                            <input class="imageInput" name="image" type="file" id="image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="button-submit-container">
                            <button id="button-for-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <%- include("partials/footer.ejs") %>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML code?

Comment: Hello Mina, i have added the EJS which is what I'm using, let me know if anything else helps you help me thanks!

Comment: The Element interface's scrollIntoView() method scrolls the element's parent container such that the element on which scrollIntoView() is called is visible to the user. Maybe you should select child element to scrollinto?

Comment: hi Deniz, i have tried selecting the child element (the li) and the container, none have worked. Just by the way, the code works but it scrolls into the object once the page opens, not once the new li element is created which is what I need and not being able to do.